# div in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

In an iframe how to make a div to hide and on mouse over the bottom of the page bring it to front again.

This is just like a control that appears in medial players,hide when mouse out and show when mouse over

```
     <div>
       <img src="play.gif"/>
       <img src="next.gif"/>
       <img src="last.gif"/>
       <img src="first.gif"/>
       <img src="previous.gif"/>
       <img src="next.gif"/>
     </div>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the iframe's page you can do something like this

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text\javascript">
     $(document).mouseover( function () {
        $("#playControls").show("slow");
     });
     $(document).mouseout( function () {
        $("#playControls").hide("slow");
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="playControls" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;"> 
       <img src="play.gif"/> 
       <img src="next.gif"/> 
       <img src="last.gif"/> 
       <img src="first.gif"/> 
       <img src="previous.gif"/> 
       <img src="next.gif"/> 
     </div> 
</body>
</html>
```